# What calendar appears to count days since December 28, 1800?

Tags: datetime, calendar, leap-year

I have been tasked to read in some data from some weird old system.
The system contains many dates but they are all oddly formatted. They are integer numbers ranging from approximately `55,000` to `80,000`.

I know two dates for certain:

```
58,112 equals February 5, 1960  (originally written as Feb 2,1960 [*])
61,439 equals March 16, 1969

[*] This typo explains some of the comments initially challenging the
    leap-year awareness of the calendar.
```

It appears to me that those integer numbers are the number of days elapsed since December 28, 1800. But I think that's a very strange date to start a calendar on. There is probably going something on with leap years and what-not that is going to cause problems later on.

Does anyone recognise this calendar? Can anyone tell me what the proper way is to convert those integers to human readable dates?

Comment: Are you sure it's not Jan 1, 1801, and you're just missing some leap days or something?

Comment: It is not so strange. For example, date on Javacards is calculated by similiar scheme starting from 1986-02-04: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5421557&messageID=10894720#10894720

Comment: @roe: No, I'm not quite sure. Although there is definitely one leap year between 1960 and 1969. That's why I'm asking here. I'm hoping somebody recognises this calendar. I had the same problem when I first encountered Julian Day calendars inside SQLite.

Comment: There is a problem with your numbers. There are 3330 days between Feb2 1960 and Mar16 1969.  But the difference between 58112 and 61439 is only 3327.  Also, Feb2 1960 - 58112 gives Dec25 1880, but Mar16 1969 - 61439 gives Dec28 1880.

Comment: Sounds like a custom julian algorithm with a leap year calculation thats incorrect? Is there any code to convert a date that we can look at? Becuase you are probably going to have to use this implementation to read the dates out again or at least convert them.

Comment: @dnagirl: My bad. The first date is February 5, not February 2.

Comment: @SanderMarechal - so you owe me and dnagirl a chunk of our time which we spent trying to figure out why the numbers were out.

Comment: @APC: My apologies. I was subscribing the dates from a different notation (EU versus US notation).

Comment: There are 3 leap days between Feb 2 1960 and March 1969. Note that 1960, 1964, and 1968 were leap years. The discrepency is probably leap year related since 3330 - 3327 = 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sounds like a bespoke system to me, but a rather strange one :)

one way to convert that will always work is use some sort of date_add() function - you don't specify which language you're using but most modern languages should have a way to add a bunch of days to a date.

regarding leap years, if those 2 dates are correct then you shouldn't have a problem, there was definitely at least 1 leap year betweek 1960 and 1969 :) it's definitely worth checking a few more recent dates just to make sure though.

Answer (score 7):

It could be Clarion. I'm working with similar old database conversion to SQL, and it figured out files (*.dat) were clarion

Comment: +1, I too think it may be [Clarion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarion_(programming_language)), a commercial programming language.

Clarion serializes dates as the number of days since December 28th 1800.
If there are time fields too, these are stored as the number of 100th's-of-a-second since midnight + 1.

Clarion dates are easy to convert using  [Excel](http://archive.clarionmag.com/cmag/v4/v4n12exceldates.html), [MSSQL](https://gist.github.com/fushnisoft/5857270), and [C#](http://www.iprogrammable.com/2007/07/31/clarion-date-and-time-in-net/).

Comment: But why does Clarion use that date in the first place?

Comment: I did some research and it looks like they chose `1801-01-01` as the lower-bound for date values (seems reasonable), but made `0` the first day of the week that `1801-01-01` is in - so that you can easily get the day-of-week by doing `date % 7` (`0` for Sunday). Quite clever, really. Mystery solved?

Answer (score 4):

I'm working with a system representing gregorian dates in julian calendar, if you want to convert a julian date to gregorian, you only need to add the quantity days to December 28 1800.

In SQL Server :

```
SELECT DATEADD(day, 58112, '18001228')
```

by example. Sorry, I don't speak english. The base date in your system is December 28 1800.

Answer (score 2):

It is not so strange. For example, date on Javacards is calculated by similiar scheme starting from 1986-02-04: http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5421557&messageID=10894720#10894720

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is Clarion Data files. Use
Edit1.Text := datetostr(encodedate(1800,12,28) );

Answer (score 0):

function convertNumberToDate($number)

```
enter code here
$dateZero = strtotime('1800-12-28');
$string = "+$number day";
return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($string, $dateZero));
enter code here
```

function convertDateToNumber($date)

```
enter code here
$dateZero = strtotime('1800-12-28');
$day = 86400;
$unix = strtotime($date);
$sub = $unix-$dateZero;
$result = $sub/$day;
return round($result,0);
enter code here
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).