# Strange integer in date field

Tags: sql-server-2008, date

So this is one I haven't come across before. I have a table containing two columns - a date, and a time - both integer. I'm trying to get the dates to be human readable but I'm not sure how they're being converted. A couple of examples:

04/26/2015 at 4:40pm comes out of the database as:

Date: 78281
Time: 6005006

04/25/2015 at 10:32am is:

Date: 78280
Time: 3796720

The date seems to be incremental, but days since when, and is this standard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apperently, the Date number is the number of days since December 28th 1800,
and the Time number is the number of milliseconds since midnight.

I've heard that sql server keeps datetime as a floating point number in this exact same style, but I have no idea why that date, but [here's another question about it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2607083/what-calendar-appears-to-count-days-since-december-28-1800)